# How are CSS value-prefixes selected by the browser?

Tags: css

Let's say I have this:

```css
.element {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}
```

That's two `position` properties in the same class, each with a different value.

Obviously, the latter does not override the former. Are they both values of the same property? How does a browser determine which of the two values to use?

Comment: It's no different than doing `.element { color: blue; color: red; }` - where `red` would "win" because it was declared last. Or, `.element { color: red; color: foo; }` - where `red` would "win" because the invalid `color: foo` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

#### Basic idea

When there are more than one duplicate property, CSS will take the last valid value.

Example 1 - All values are valid, so CSS take the last one:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;   /* The first valid value */
  background-color: black; /* The last valid value */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Example 2 - Last value is not valid, so CSS take the last valid one:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red; /* The last valid value */
  background-color: 123; /* Invalid color value */
  background-color: 456; /* Invalid color value */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

#### Why do we do this?

It is to ensure proper browser support.

Take your example for instance, the `sticky` value for `position` property is [not widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) by most browsers. And some browsers only support the vendor prefixed value.

So, this snippet:

```
.element {
  /* If browser does not support standard value, use this prefixed value */
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* If browser support this, use this standard value */
  position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: "Last valid value" was the answer I was looking for. Thanks.